# JavaScript - Scroll to bottom of Div - Keeps on scrolling down without stop

Tags: javascript, scroll

So I have this function which scrolls down to the bottom of the page, and to the bottom of the scrollable div `#log`:

```
function gotoConsole() {
    var console = document.getElementById('log');

    window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
    window.setInterval(function() {
        console.scrollTop = console.scrollHeight;
    }, 250);
}
```

It does the job, it scrolls down to the page and scrolls to the bottom of the div. But the problem is; The div keeps on going down, I cannot scroll up.

The `gotoConsole()` function is called only once after the user clicks on a button.

What is the problem with this function? I cannot use jQuery for this.

Comment: you need to use `clearInterval` somewhere after scrolling is ended

Comment: have you used ```setInterval```

Comment: Seeing a variable named `console` makes me want to scream at my monitor.

Comment: thats a function and the problem you are saying can only ocurr when you are calling the function at some event or interval

Comment: @Mitch maybe would be better to use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/vg11e6kk/, now problem that `setInterval` is not stopped, and when you are trying to scroll, `setInterval` fires after `250` and scroll to bottom again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you may be misunderstanding `setInterval`. `setInterval()` will repeat **infinitely** unless you specifically clear it using `clearInterval`.

I believe what you're after is `setTimeout` - it functions very similarly to `setInterval`, though rather than repeating, it only runs *once*.

```
function gotoConsole() {
    var myConsole = document.getElementById('log');

    window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        myConsole.scrollTop = myConsole.scrollHeight;
    }, 250);
}
```

---

**Side note:**

Setting a variable to `console` is a major red flag.

When writing/debugging JavaScript, your best friend is very often going to be 
`console.log()`. When you set a variable to the same name, you lose the ability to reference `console` within that scope without doing `window.console.log()` which is a cumbersome annoyance.